# How to access a svg underneath another one?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am drawing an axis and a clickable circle using d3, the circle is enclosed by the axis.
I have a HTML file, which calls two Javascript-files to draw them separately. However, my circle's svg is covered by the axis' and cannot be clicked.
Are there anyway I can set circle's svg on the top?

Comment: set pointer-events="none" on the elements you don't want to be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set pointer-events="none" in the css to stop interaction. Or use the z-axis